# How can I make a Jira REST API call to get a specific value?

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am making a Jira REST API call using this example url:

http://example.com/rest/api/2/search/?jql=project=example%20and%20type=test&fields=customfield_14600

Here is an example of the returned JSON

```
{
    "expand":"names",
    "startAt":0,
    "maxResults":50,
    "total":2,
    "issues":[
        {
            "expand":"examples",
            "id":"1111",
            "self":"https://example.com/rest/api/2/issue/111111",
            "key":"EX-1111",
            "fields":{
                "customfield_14600":{
                    "self":"https://example.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/1111",
                    "value":"Common",
                    "id":"11111",
                    "disabled":false
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "expand":"examples",
            "id":"1111",
            "self":"https://example.com/rest/api/2/issue/111111",
            "key":"EX-1111",
            "fields":{
                "customfield_14600":{
                    "self":"https://example.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/1111",
                    "value":"Uncommon",
                    "id":"11111",
                    "disabled":false
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[Here is an image of the returned JSON with better formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16xFw.png)

What URL would I use to only return the issues with the value "Common" for the customfield_14600? Basically I am trying to return the number of issues with the "**Common**" value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a JQL query, you could add another filter to check that the custom field you need has the value you require, as such:

```
project = example AND type = test AND cf[14600] = "Common"
```

Or, if you know the name of the custom field and/or prefer it to be readable:

```
project = example AND type = test AND "Field name" = "Common"
```

You can check [the manual](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver/advanced-searching-939938733.html) for more operators/keywords.

On another topic, I would recommend using the `POST` endpoint instead of the `GET` one for searches that include complex queries. Check [the REST API documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.5.3/#api/2/search-searchUsingSearchRequest) for instructions.

Comment: What would the URL to make that call look like. I tried the following and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

@Yousuf, for your question:

Example:

```
rest/api/2/search?jql=project = NAME AND labels = Sprint1 AND cf[15200] = \"4771\""
```

Or just use Postman and add the JQL query as a param. Then see the code snippet there. The URL is ready.